# UIWebview slows down after a period of time

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, uiwebview

We have a complex app that uses a `UIWebView` to display some information at a certain point. We have an *OpenGL* layer that stops drawing while the `UIWebview` is displayed, and we're using about 128 Meg of ram (according to monitors). The page is about 10 screens worth of table, and is static content. Javascript is used on setup, but that's it.

We've noticed that the page loads and is responsive, and then after scrolling the view up and down a few times, the CPU hits about 18% - not in our code. This happens on `DidReceiveMemory` warning (though the device is not short of memory), so it feels like a garbage collector or something. The 18% then remains until the view is freed off. Returning to the view again and the newly created `UIWebview` will be responsive again, with the same behaviour of slowing down after a bit of brisk scrolling.

We clear the `NSURLCache` on `didReceiveMemoryWarning` (and give the OS back lots of ram). Does anyone have other suggestions, as the responsiveness drops off a cliff on older devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out if you present the Renderbuffer from the OpenGL layer every frame while a UIWebView is visible, this slow down kicks in. The other instance we used a UIWebview we had paused the renderer, so it didn't matter

Ensuring that

```
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, viewRenderbuffer);
[m_pContext presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER];
```

Does not run (or pausing the display link) fixed the problem for us. Hope it is useful to someone, as it has been puzzling us for days.